Android Application gets blocked on splash screen due to AppUpdateManager
I have a working Android application. After recent Android updates users are facing issues of app stuck on the splash screen.
On the splash screen, I check for updates and proceed to the next activity if no updates are available.
private void checkUpdates() {
        // Creates instance of the manager.
        AppUpdateManager appUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(this);

        // Returns an intent object that you use to check for an update.
        Task<AppUpdateInfo> appUpdateInfoTask = appUpdateManager.getAppUpdateInfo();

        // Checks that the platform will allow the specified type of update.
        appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener(appUpdateInfo -> {          
            if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE
                    && appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE)) {

                //start update
                try {

                    appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(
                            // Pass the intent that is returned by 'getAppUpdateInfo()'.
                            appUpdateInfo,
                            // Or 'AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE' for flexible updates.
                            AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE,
                            // The current activity making the update request.
                            this,
                            // Include a request code to later monitor this update request.
                            FORCE_UPDATE_REQUEST_CODE);

                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } else {
                // update not available - so proceed to appropriate landing page
                redirectToLandingPage();
            }
        });
    }

Upon debug, I found that 'addOnSuccessListener' is not getting called by AppUpdateManager.
Please helm me find solution for this.
I tried to debug by checking if 'appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener' is getting called and found that it is not getting called by AppUpdateManager.
